# How to have independent elasticsearch local nodes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm writing unit tests that use local nodes and want them to be independent such that if they're running concurrently, they shouldn't affect each other. Can local nodes be named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will name a local cluster:

```
final node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().clusterName('aoeu').local(true).node()
```

If the name is 'unique' (eg includes the hostname, working directory, and timestamp), it will keep the tests independent.